# organizing a table

Tags: tables

[image: column (her results) must be next to the column (my results)]
Hi: 
I wanted to pull the column (her results) up to be next to the column (my results).
can someone help me please?.
the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}


\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{The table caption}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=1.0] S[table-format=1.6] S[table-format=1.4] S[table-format=1.3]}

\toprule
{$t$ (\si{\nano\meter})} & {$W$ (\si{\micro\meter})} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{My results} \\
\cmidrule{3-5}
                         &                           & {Re}     & {\splitcell{Theor.\\Overlap\\factor}} & {\splitcell{Theor.\\MPA\\(\si{dB/mm})}} \\
\midrule
25                       & 8                         & 1.447413 & 0.9627                                & 2.128 \\
                         & 4                         & 1.446128 & 0.9538                                & 1.20  \\
\midrule
31                       & 8                         & 1.448499 & 0.9377                                & 4.196 \\
                         & 4                         & 1.446889 & 0.9571                                & 2.78  \\
\bottomrule
                         &                           & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Her results} \\
 \cmidrule{3-5} % 6-8
                         &                                 &                                      & {\splitcell{Theor.\\Overlap\\factor}} & {\splitcell{Theor.\\MPA\\(\si{dB/mm})}} \\
\midrule
25                       & 8                          &     & 0.9627                               & 2.128 \\
                         & 4                           &   & 0.9538                               & 1.20  \\
\midrule
31                       & 8                          &   & 0.9377                               & 4.196 \\
                         & 4                          &    & 0.9571                               & 2.78  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Should just be a matter of rearranging the input.

Comment: The simplest way is split content of your table into two tabular, something like this: \begin{table}\caption ...\begin{tabular}<stuff for my results>end{tabular}\begin{tabular}<stuff for her results>\end{tabular}\end{table}. Another way is reformat table, i.e. extend number of columns from 5 to 10.

Comment: Zarko, I tried both ideas and could not get it. The column (her results) always appear below the table!!!. Could you past the solution code?

Comment: [This question already has an answer here:](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196395/table-with-two-multicolumns/196405?noredirect=1#comment454955_196405) wrote few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer.

```
   \begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{The table caption}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=1.0] S[table-format=1.6] S[table-format=1.4] S[table-format=1.3]|S[table-format=1.6] S[table-format=1.4] S[table-format=1.3]}

\toprule

         {$t$ (\si{\nano\meter})}     &  {$W$ (\si{\micro\meter})} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Her results} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{My results} \\
 \cmidrule{3-8} % 6-8
                         &                                 &                                      & {\splitcell{Theor.\\Overlap\\factor}} & {\splitcell{Theor.\\MPA\\(\si{dB/mm})}} & {Re}     & {\splitcell{Theor.\\Overlap\\factor}} & {\splitcell{Theor.\\MPA\\(\si{dB/mm})}} \\
\midrule
25                       & 8                          &     & 0.9627                               & 2.128 & 1.447413 & 0.9627                                & 2.128 \\
                         & 4                           &   & 0.9538                               & 1.20  & 1.446128 & 0.9538                                & 1.20  \\
\midrule
31                       & 8                          &   & 0.9377                               & 4.196 & 1.448499 & 0.9377                                & 4.196 \\
                         & 4                          &    & 0.9571                               & 2.78  & 1.446889 & 0.9571                                & 2.78  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]