# Typesetting a table with headline spaning more then one cell

Tags: tables

In the end, the table should look like

[image]

How to make the top row with "Team sheet" span more than one column? This is how far I came:

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Columns_spanning_multiple_rows

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please show us what you have tried so far.  Any standard reference for LaTeX discusses tables and there are many examples on this site.

Comment: I m new to it  ,I need "team sheet" as  one column and it should have 3 sub columns in my table .

Comment: @NishaNuthan Welcome to Tex.Stackexchange! Please do us a favour and copy the code from your document and past it into your question - this makes it easier to read than the photo of your screen.

Comment: Can you translate your text in question in normal /oxford :-) / English, please? on your picture I see two small tables, if this observation help you.

Comment: You're probably looking for `multicolumn`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131867/using-multicolumn-in-latex

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

The following code serves as MWE (Minimal Working Example) for your future questions. For sure similar question was asked before ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

{
   \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | l |}
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Team sheet}        \\
    \hline
Goalkeeper  &   GK  &   Paul Robinson   \\
    \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Goalkeeper}
            &   GK  &   Paul Robinson   \\
            &   GK  &   Paul Robinson   \\
            &   GK  &   Paul Robinson   \\
            &   GK  &   Paul Robinson   \\
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Goalkeeper}
            &   GK  &   Paul Robinson   \\
            &   GK  &   Paul Robinson   \\
            &   GK  &   Paul Robinson   \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Goalkeeper}
            &   GK  &   Paul Robinson   \\
            &   GK  &   Paul Robinson   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```