# Simple way to have a table with a different number of columns in each row

Tags: tables

So my question is how would i go about presenting the following table of emails correctly so it displays the metadata in the first line and then the subject of the email in the lines following.

In crude ASCII diagram I would want it to look something like the following

```
[sender email        ] [Recipient email         ][Date       ]

[TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL ]
```

Below is the LaTeX code that needs adaptation.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} |} 
\hline
 Sender & Recipient & Date and Time Of Sending\\ 
\hline
\hline
   chkwasher@comcast.net & checkwashing@gmail.com & 6/31/2006 21:00\\  
\hline
 TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL \\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! It looks like you are looking for the `\multicolumn` command.  See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131867/15925

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment, along with a `multicolumn{3}{...}{...}` directive for the text of the email messages. To give the table a more "open" look, I would omit all vertical rules and employ fewer, but well-spaced horizontal rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}>{\RaggedRight}p{\textwidth}@{}}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\small}X}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YYY @{}} 
\toprule
 Sender & Recipient & Date and Time of Sending\\ 
\midrule
\url{chkwasher@comcast.net} & \url{checkwashing@gmail.com} & 6/31/2006 21:00\\ 
\addlinespace
\mc{TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL 
    TEXT OF EMAIL TEXT OF EMAIL} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```