# How to design multi-row and multi-column tables in latex?

Tags: tables

I am trying to design this table, But this contains multi-columns

[image]

How to go after this:

```
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Type} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Dataset} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\#Features} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\#Avg. sparsity} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\#Nodes} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\# Clusters} \\ \hline
                           & Facebook                     & 1284                            & 80\%                                 & 300                          & 20                               \\
Social Network             & Gplus                        & 1284                            & 80\%                                 & 300                          & 20                               \\
                           & Twitter                      & 1284                            & 80\%                                 & 300                          & 20                               \\
                           & Cora                         & 321                             & 19\%                                 & 100                          & 4                                \\
Citation Dataset           & Citeseer                     & 321                             & 20\%                                 & 100                          & 3                                \\
                           & Pubmed                       & 321                             & 20\%                                 & 100                          & 6                               
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But it's not showing as I want:

[image]

How to design like that image? Should I use any extra package?

Comment: The multicolumn command can be used for the entries in the first row. Apart from that, I'd recommend to avoid vertical lines and to use the horizontal lines from the booktabs package. For an improved alignment of the numbers, you could use the siunitx package.

Comment: Define the table with all data columns you need, then combine header cells with `\multicolumn{<#cols>}{<l/r/c>}{<text>}` (see e.g. https://texblog.org/2012/12/21/multi-column-and-multi-row-cells-in-latex-tables/ or https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Rows_spanning_multiple_columns) Related: [Using multicolumn in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131867/33413)

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the column widths here, nor to use `multirow`.

Comment: The code in your question seems to be only loosely related to the image. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @leandriis I corrected, Please check.

Comment: With editing your question you change it completely. Showed table haven't any multi column cell. Consequently your question become unclear or at least to broad (aka "write my table instead of me"). If you have new question, please ask it as such and provide an MWE, which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Maybe not the most semantically valid, but the easiest way is to put _Social_ in the second row and _Network_ in the third row. Use `c` columns instead of `l` if you want to center (`\begin{tabular}{cccccc}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I tried and it's same as i wanted :

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|cccccc}


\toprule
column 1 & column 2 & column 3    & column 4 & column 5 & column 6       & column 6  & column 6  \\ 
\toprule
\multirow{4}{*}{two rows} &  column 1 & column 2 & column 3    & column 4 & column 5 & column 6       & column 6   \\  

\cline{2-8}
&  column 1 & column 2 & column 3    & column 4 & column 5 & column 6       & column 6   \\  
\cline{2-8}
&  column 1 & column 2 & column 3    & column 4 & column 5 & column 6       & column 6   \\  
\cline{2-8}
&  column 1 & column 2 & column 3    & column 4 & column 5 & column 6       & column 6   \\  

\cline{1-8}
\multirow{2}{*}{two rows} &  column 1 & column 2 & column 3    & column 4 & column 5 & column 6       & column 6   \\  

\cline{2-8}
&  column 1 & column 2 & column 3    & column 4 & column 5 & column 6       & column 6   \\  
\cline{2-8}
&  column 1 & column 2 & column 3    & column 4 & column 5 & column 6       & column 6   \\  

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Some elementary description how to design tales you can find in [WikiBooks/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). For further design of your tables is also worth to see  ["Wie Tabellen eigentlich aussehen sollten"](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/). Learned from both links, you can design the following table, which has multi column and multi row cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c ccc ccc}
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{two rows} 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{3-columns cell} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{3-columns cell}   \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
        & column 1  & column 2  & column 3  & column 4  & column 5  & column 6          \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Social Network}  
        & item 1    & item 2    & then 3    & item 4    & item 5    & item 6            \\
        & item 1    & item 2    & then 3    & item 4    & item 5    & item 6            \\
        & item 1    & item 2    & then 3    & item 4    & item 5    & item 6            \\
        & item 1    & item 2    & then 3    & item 4    & item 5    & item 6            \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{4}{*}{Citation Dataset}
        & item 1    & item 2    & then 3    & item 4    & item 5    & item 6            \\
        & item 1    & item 2    & then 3    & item 4    & item 5    & item 6            \\
        & item 1    & item 2    & then 3    & item 4    & item 5    & item 6            \\
        & item 1    & item 2    & then 3    & item 4    & item 5    & item 6            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example of professional table design}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you check the updated image, please? I accidentally used the wrong image earlier.

Comment: @AadityaUra, in both received answer you got a way how to design multi column and multi row cells. Now you change question completely. It would be fer that you ask new question and from received select one, which the best way solve your problem as it is stated in the first version of question.

Answer (score 2):

Does that help ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc|ccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{two rows} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{three columns} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{three other columns} \\
\cline{2-7}
                          & column 1 & column 2 & column 3    & column 4 & column 5 & column 6          \\    
\midrule
\midrule
line 1                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{columns 1 and 2} & then 3 & then 4 & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{then 5 and 6 with vert bar} \\
\midrule
line 2                    & \multirow{2}{*}{2 rows' cell} & lorem & ipsum & & & \\
line 3                    &                               & lorem & ipsum & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example of what you can do...}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As [@leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513531/how-to-design-multi-row-and-multi-column-tables-in-latex/513555#comment1298672_513531) says,

> The code in your question seems to be only loosely related to the image.

Might be helpful to be more precise in what you want to achieve.

Comment: It was very helpful.